# Beim oder während

Tags: meaning

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *während* und *beim*?

Beispiel:

> Während des Schreibens einer E-Mail habe ich verstanden, dass ...

Und

> Beim Schreiben einer E-Mail habe ich verstanden, dass ...

Comment: Ich gehe mal davon aus, daß es um Bedeutungsunterschiede geht? *Bei* steht immer mit dem Dativ, *während* kann mit dem Genitiv stehen. Außerdem kann *während* auch eine Subjunktion sein.

Answer (score 3):

- *"Während"* bezieht sich immer auf eine Tätigkeit oder einen Zeitraum

  > **Während des zweiten Weltkriegs** litten viele Menschen Hunger.
  >   Das sprechen mit dem Fahrer **während der Fahrt** ist strengstens untersagt.
- *"Bei"* ("bei der" oder "beim = bei dem") kann sich auf Orte oder Personen beziehen

  > **Beim Arzt** musste ich nicht lange warten.
  >   Die Kreuzung **beim Rathaus** ist ab heute gesperrt.
- "Während" kann auch als Subjunktion verwendet werden:

  > temporal: Helga trank Wein **während** sie das Buch las.
  >   adversativ: Dieter, Helmut und Lothar haben braune Haare, **während** Heinz strohblond ist.
- *"Während"* wird meist mit dem Genitiv verwendet, kann aber (vor allem umgangssprachlich) auch mit dem Dativ verwendet werden

  > Genitiv: **Während des Essens** soll man nicht sprechen.
  >   Dativ: **Während dem Essen** soll man nicht sprechen.
- *"Bei"* verlangt immer den Dativ:

  > **Bei mir** bist du schön.
  >   **Bei dem** (=beim) **Essen** soll man nicht sprechen.

Comment: Zu "Während mit Dativ": Ich finde deine Formulierung "kann aber (vor allem umgangssprachlich) auch mit Dativ verwendet werden" eine Spur zur weitgehend. Ja, es ***wird*** so verwendet, aber es ist schon ***sehr*** umgangssprachlich. Ich würde eher formulieren: "... wird aber umgangsprachlich auch mit Dativ verwendet", ohne dieser alltagsadäquaten Schludrigkeit mit "kann" einen Passierschein auszustellen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Wievielfache Vergrößerung hatte denn das Mikroskop, das Du benutzt hast, um dieses Haar zu spalten? *grins*

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf  Ja, beim Hubert erwarte ich halt höchste Präzision in allem, deshalb bin ich über diesen Haarriss in seinem Gedankengebäude gestolpert.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Im geschriebenen Deutsch unterscheidet man verschiedene Textsorten, und je nach Textsorte gelten unterschiedliche Regeln. In wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten dürfen Personalpronomen allerhöchstens in der dritten Person verwendet werden (und das auch nur wohlbegründbaren Ausnahmen). Dasselbe gilt für Gesetzestexte. In Zeitungsartikeln ist es ähnlich. In E-Mails und Postings in sozialen Medien sind diese Wörter aber überdurchschnittlich häufig anzutreffen, und dort würde es niemand als Fehler ansehen, wenn jemand *ich, du, wir* schreiben würde. ...

Comment: ... Und auch in der gesprochenen Sprache gibt es Regeln, die vom Verwendungszweck abhängen. Es macht einen Unterschied, ob du bei einem Bewerbungsgespräch über dein bisheriges Leben berichtest oder ob du einem Freund weit nach Mitternacht bei der vierten Flasche Wein einen autobiographischen Bericht erstattest. Da gelten ganz einfach andere Regeln. Und in lockerer Atmosphäre ist es durchaus **korrekt,** auf *»während«* den Dativ folgen zu lassen.

Answer (score 2):

#### 1) Hauptsächlich: Stilistik

Der Unterschied zwischen "während" und "beim" in den Beispielen aus der Frage ist vor allem ein stilistischer.

> Beim Eisessen ist mir eingefallen, dass ich noch Käse kaufen muss.
>
> Während ich Eis aß, fiel mir ein, dass ich noch Käse kaufen musste.
>
> Während der Würm-Eiszeit herrschte in Mitteleuropa ein deutlich kühleres Klima als heute.

"Beim..." verwendet man vor allem in formloser, umgangssprachlicher Rede. "Während..." wird vor allem in höher formalisierten, schriftlichen Texten eingesetzt.

Dein Beispielsatz mit dem E-Mail-Schreiben klingt mit "während" zu umständlich und hölzern. Du würdest normalerweise eher sagen:

> Beim Schreiben der E-Mail habe ich plötzlich kapiert, dass...

denn dein Satz ist offenbar Teil einer formlosen Kommunikationssituation.

In einem Roman könnte man dagegen lesen:

> Während Franz nun das lange geplante E-Mail an den Ortsvorsteher schrieb, ging ihm plötzlich ein Licht auf: Hatten seine Nachbarn nicht immer schon ihre Knöterichstauden...

Also: Grundregel: *Beim* ist gut für formlose Anlässe, *während* für förmliche.

Du schreibst der Polizei oder der Versicherung:

> Während ich nach Hause ging, wurde ich von einem Tretroller angefahren.

Du erzählst deinem Kumpel:

> Beim Nachhausegehen hat mich ein Tretroller angefahren.

#### 2) Auch ein bisschen: Semantik

Es gibt aber auch eine semantische Komponente<sup>1</sup>, allerdings ist sie nicht sehr dominant.

In bestimmten Kontexten kann das *beim* anzeigen, dass ein inhaltlicher (bis hin zu kausaler) Zusammenhang zwischen den beiden Handlungen besteht:

> Beim Schreiben des E-Mails an Maria fiel mir ein, dass ich ihr noch nicht zum Abitur gratuliert hatte

Hier gehen wir davon aus, dass dem Autor das Abitur einfiel, weil er gerade sowieso an Maria dachte.

> Während ich ein E-Mail an Fritz schrieb, fiel mir ein, dass ich Maria noch nicht zum Abitur gratuliert hatte.

Hier verstehen wir die Situation eher so, dass der Autor beim Schreiben an Fritz unkonzentriert aus irgend einem Grund an Maria gedacht hat. Die Sache mit Maria hätte ihm auch beim Bügeln oder beim Joggen einfallen können, obwohl auch diese Ttigkeiten mit Maria nichts zu tun haben und somit als "während des Bügelns, während des Joggens" in den Satz eingeflochten werden müssten, wäre denn die semantische Aufladung des *beim* zwingend.

Wie man nun aber an der letzten Zeile oben sieht ("beim Bügeln, beim Joggen"), ist das *beim* nicht zwangsläufig ein Indikator von inhaltlichem (oder gar kausalem) Zusammenhang.

Deutlich ist das Beispiel von Johnl:

> Beim Skifahren in den Rocky Mountains wurde ihm Geld gestohlen

Hier gehen wir davon aus, dass der Diebstahl am Ort des Skifahrens stattfand. Es wäre sehr ungewöhnlich (oder mindestens extrem schludrig-umgangssprachlich) zu sagen:

> Beim Skifahren in den Rocky Mountains wurde ihm in Deutschland Geld gestohlen.

Hier würde fast jeder automatisch sagen, und zwar auch im umgangssprachlichen Verkehr:

> Während er in den Rocky Mountains skifahren war, wurde ihm in Deutschland Geld gestohlen.

#### Schlussfolgerung

Dies bringt mich nun zum Schluß, dass das *beim* ein semantische Komponente der **Kolokalität** trägt: Handlungen, die mit *beim* verbunden werden, sehen wir als **am gleichen Ort** stattfindend an. (Ob dann noch eine Kausalitätsverbindung zwischen ihnen besteht, entscheidet der Hörer/Leser wohl nur gestützt auf seine Lebenserfahrung.)

Kolokalität:

> Beim Rettichschneiden habe ich mir die Hand verstaucht
>
> Beim Radiohören ist mir eine gute Idee gekommen
>
> Beim Autofahren wird mir immer schlecht

Umgekehrt kann man aber nicht sagen, dass *während* zwingend lokale Dissoziation anzeigt. Man kann sagen:

> Während der Mondlandung habe ich Marmelade eingekocht (keine Kolokaliät)
>
> Während der Autofahrt wurde mir schlecht (Kolokalität)

---

**Nebenbei**

Lustigerweise kann man auch sagen:

> **Während** er in den Rocky Mountains **beim** Skifahren war, wurde ihm in Deutschland Geld gestohlen.

---

<sup>1</sup> Darauf haben die Kommentatoren Volker Landgraf und Johnl freundlicherweise hingewiesen.

Comment: Einen kleinen Bedeutungsunterschied würde ich doch sehen: Wenn ein kausaler Zusammenhang besteht, würde ich eher zu "beim" tendieren. Also: "*während ich duschte* (meine Gedanken schweiften frei umher) habe ich plötzlich verstanden, warum ein Prisma Licht in Spektralfarben zerlegt", aber "*Beim Schreiben der E-Mail an den Professor* (meine Gedanken waren mit genau diesem Thema beschäftigt) habe ich plötzlich verstanden...

Comment: Ich weiß ja nicht. Auch die hier genannten Beispiele zeigen m.E., dass es nicht nur um einen förmlich/formlos-Unterschied gehen kann: Das Hintergrundereignis _Während der Würm-Eiszeit_ könnte man überhaupt nicht grammatisch mit einer _bei_-Konstruktion ausdrücken (warum nicht?). Falsch wohl auch: _*Beim Skifahren in den Rocky Mountains wurde ihm in Deutschland Geld gestohlen_ (problemlos möglich mit _während_). _Bei_ kodiert offenbar eine besondere Nähebeziehung zwischen den beiden Ereignissen.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf  Da hast du Recht. "Beim" zeigt in der Tat oft eine engere, vielleicht sogar kausale Verbindung an. Muss ich wohl noch ergänzen...

Comment: Im 3. Beispiel, ist »das E-Mail« ein Tippfehler? Der elektronischen Brief ist mir noch nie anders als »die E-Mail« untergekommen. Klingt in meinen Ohren ohne jeden Zweifel nach einem Fehler.

Comment: "Während der Würm-Eiszeit herrschte in Mitteleuropa ein deutlich kühleres Klima als heute." Nach meinem Sprachgefühl geht hier "Bei" überhaupt nicht. Wie wäre es stattdessen mit "In der Würm-Eiszeit ..."